# How to implement queuing for incoming API Requests in Python based FastAPI Web Application

Tags: python, queue, fastapi, message-queue

We have a FastAPI Application that recieves some data related to the remote servers in the form of API Calls. We are looking forward to make this a production grade application. For This we need to implement the Queuing for incoming API Calls. Below is the expected traffic which may come.

1. Incoming Concurrent API Request: ~ 200K
2. Limitation with No. Database connection for Postgres/oracle using sqlalchemy, max no. concurrent no of DB connections allowed.
3. Dynamic Scalability depending upon the load.

Currently, this app is running as a Service on Windows Server 2019 without Docker

We refered this article to implement and try the following: https://johnsturgeon.me/2022/12/10/asyncio-queue

We tried implementing asyncio.queue but this does not serves the purpose, as soon as just 100 Concurrent requests comes in the app is just freezed and we get a timeout (timeout=60s) exception in the caller. Below is the code for your reference

**queue_module.py**

```
import asyncio

fifo_queue = asyncio.Queue()

async def fifo_worker():
    print("Starting DB Worker")
    while True:
        task, result_future = await fifo_queue.get()
        print(f"Got a job: (size of remaining queue: {fifo_queue.qsize()})")

        try:
            result = await task()
            result_future.set_result(result)
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle exceptions if necessary
            result_future.set_exception(e)
```

**small part of r_device.py:**

```
@router.post("/", response_model=Show_Device, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_device(request: Create_Device, log_request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db),
                        response: Response = Response(), current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user)):
    async def create_device_task():
        api_logger.info(f"Create Device Request Received",
                        extra={"ids": {"id": request.id}, "action": log_actions["0"],
                               "caller": await caller_details(log_request)})
        existing_device = retrieve_device(id=request.id, db=db, logger=api_logger)

        if existing_device:
            api_logger.info(f"Device Present in Database, Updating Device",
                            extra={"action": log_actions["2"], "ids": {"id": request.id}})
            updated_device = update_device_by_id(id=request.id, device=request, db=db, logger=api_logger)
            response.status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
            api_logger.info(f"Device Updated, Returning Updated Device",
                            extra={"ids": {"id": request.id}, "action": log_actions["3"]})
            return updated_device
        else:
            request.create_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            request.last_detected_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            api_logger.info(f"Device Not Present in Database Creating New Device",
                            extra={"action": log_actions["1"], "ids": {"id": request.id}})
            device = create_new_device(device=request, db=db, logger=api_logger)
            api_logger.info(f"Device Created, Returning New Device",
                            extra={"ids": {"id": request.id}, "action": log_actions["3"]})
            return device

    # Create a future to store the result
    result_future = asyncio.Future()

    # Put the task and the future into the queue
    await fifo_queue.put((create_device_task, result_future))

    # Wait for the result from the future
    result = await result_future

    # Now 'result' contains the value returned by create_device_task
    return result
```

Comment: Did you do your benchmark in a production deployment with gunicorn or did you test with uvicorn? Docs for reference: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/

Comment: Also remember that async does not mean parallel, so unless your underlying libraries (such as `retrieve_device` and `create_new_device` for example, which doesn't seem to be async) are async compatible, you'll block the main thread when executing those tasks. You'll also have to affix a time qualifier to your requirements (200k requests over a second? ten seconds? a minute?), and how expensive these operations are. A profiler will be your friend to find out where things are slow.